# Is there any way to trim data automatically

Tags: mysql, trim

Lets I have a table named `myTable` in `mysql` with Three field

```
1. id int autoincrement
2. product_id varchar(20) not null
3. product_name varchar(200) not null
```

Now I want to keep data in `product_id` and `product_name` without white-space.

Comment: you mean without using trim() ?? automatically while inserting ?

Comment: @CodingAnt yes. when data stored into database then mysql keep it without white-space

Comment: what about Triggers ?

Comment: if I use Triggers then is database will be slow?

Comment: using replace? but you need to use it on insert REPLACE( product_name , ' ' , '' ) - that will remove all white spaces

Comment: better use trim while inserting in DB before , keeping it simple . And use update with trim for existing records

Comment: I have lots of query to insert data. even I don't know how many query I use to insert. so that it is impossible to change my all query

Comment: You need to clarify which whitespace you want to remove.  Leading, trailing or all whitespace.

Comment: only leading and trailing. example if I stored `' test'` then it stored as `'test'`. if I stored `'test '` then it stored as `'test'`. if I stored `' test '` then it stored as `'test'`

Answer (score 0):

you have created that two fields with varchar type. So that means it will not take whitespace even if your string contains.

For more clarification : [Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL Documentation regarding spaces in varchar fields. It is important to note that this is dependent on which version of MySQL you are using:

> For VARCHAR columns, trailing spaces in excess of the column length are truncated prior to insertion and a warning is generated, regardless of the SQL mode in use. For CHAR columns, truncation of excess trailing spaces from inserted values is performed silently regardless of the SQL mode.
>
> VARCHAR values are not padded when they are stored. Handling of trailing spaces is version-dependent. As of MySQL 5.0.3, trailing spaces are retained when values are stored and retrieved, in conformance with standard SQL. Before MySQL 5.0.3, trailing spaces are removed from values when they are stored into a VARCHAR column; this means that the spaces also are absent from retrieved values.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Comment: I have lots of query to insert data. even I don't know how many query I use to insert. so that it is impossible to change my all query. That's why I search a system to keep data in database without leading and trailing spaces

Comment: The query I provided can fix your insertion queries.  You can write a separate `UPDATE` query that can remove the leading and trailing spaces that are already stored in these fields in the table. But if you have lots of queries, I don't know what you're expecting us to help you with, you'll need to fix your queries at some point in time, either now, or later.

Comment: I just want to know is there any system to keep data with removing leading and trailing white-space. I don't use any mechanism in my query. I just want to know is it possible?

Comment: You _have to_ read the documentation if you want to understand how trailing spaces are stored in varchar fields. And if this is the information you _only_ wanted, why didn't you state that in your post?